# getBoundingClientRec() and detecting right coordinates on a canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, getboundingclientrect

folks.
Well, I just want to draw on a canvas that's moved away from (0,0) coordinates and is resized.

I don't really understand anymore, I've tried many things and this won't work. I've discovered the getBoundingClientRect() method, I've discovered how to resize my canvas (the appearance as well as the inner bitmap), but these won't work.

I just want to draw lines in my canvas and do a browser based paint. I'd really appreciate if someone is kind enough and could give me a spotlight.

I think the problem relies on the JavaScript file, because everything else works fine. It's the part of detecting the right coordinates where everything fails. And more specifically, the problem is in the y coordinate, since the x coordinate seemed to be detected right.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
/*Code to make the canvas size the same as the div size*/
/*Logic*/

//get reference to the canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

function fitToContainer(canvas){
    //make it visually fill the positioned parent
    canvas.style.width = '100%';
    canvas.style.height = '100%';
    //then, set the internal canva's size to match the container
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

}

fitToContainer(canvas); 

//Code to make your drawing
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//where ctx means context

//function to try to catch the right x,y coordinates inside the canvas

let scaleX, scaleY;

function  getMousePos(canvas, e) {
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // abs. size of element
    scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width;    // relationship bitmap vs. element for x
    scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;  // relationship bitmap vs. element for y
  
    return {
      x: (e.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX,   // scale mouse coordinates after they have
      y: (e.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY     // been adjusted to be relative to element
    }
}



//variables
let painting = false;

function startPosition(e, canvas){
    painting = true;
    draw(e, canvas);
}

function lastPosition(){
    painting = false;
    ctx.beginPath();
}

function draw(e, canvas){
    if (!painting) return;
    //painting set up
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    let coordinates = getMousePos(canvas, e);

    //lines below are to begin drawing
    ctx.lineTo(coordinates[x], coordinates[y]);
    ctx.stroke();

   // console.log(`x: ${e.clientX}, y: ${e.clientY}`);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(coordinates[x], coordinates[y]);
    //ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

function innerPointerPostion(e){
    console.log(`Real position\n x: ${e.clientX}, y: ${e.clientY}`);
}

//event listeners
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',draw(canvas));
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',startPosition(canvas));
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',lastPosition);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', innerPointerPostion);
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

}

h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.flexContainer{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

    display: flex;
}
.canvasContainer{
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #0b0d9c;
    position: relative;
    height: 160px;
    padding: .5rem .5rem .5rem .5rem;
    
}

canvas{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: .1rem;
    border-color: #000000;

    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script async src="canvasOutlookAndLogic.js"></script>
    
    <title>Just draw it</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Make any drawing you want</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="canvasContainer">
        <canvas>
            Space to draw
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have your code working in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb7zrc8d/

The only two changes I made were to stop passing the "canvas" object between functions, because it was not being passed correctly and it exists as a global object in your code, and I changed these lines:

```
ctx.lineTo(coordinates.x, coordinates.y);
ctx.moveTo(coordinates.x, coordinates.y);
```

Because coordinates[x] means your are using a non-existent variable named "x" to index coordinates, instead of looking for the "x" property of coordinates.